# Call to method setCurrentUri fails in Symfony/SonataUserBundle setup

Tags: symfony, sonata-user-bundle, knpmenubundle

I am trying to set up Symfony with the SonataUserBundle. User registration and login works fine. When I try to call up the `/profile` view, however I get the following error:

```
Attempted to call method "setCurrentUri" on class "Knp\Menu\MenuItem" in F:\<my project path>\vendor\sonata-project\user-bundle\Block\ProfileMenuBlockService.php line 91. Did you mean to call: "setCurrent"?
```

The last notice in the "event list" before the error is

```
INFO - [cms::renderBlock] block.id=53, block.type=sonata.user.block.menu
```

Has anyone encountered this error before and can provide information on how to resolve it?

TIA
Matt

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What versions of `KnpMenu` and `SonataBlockBundle` are you using? Please check your `composer.json` to be sure.

The `setCurrentUri` method has been deprecated as of `KnpMenu` v. 2.0, and the `composer.json` of `SonataBlockBundle` does not require `KnpMenu` anywhere but in `dev` install. So, this leads to a possibility that you could have required a fresher version of `knplabs/knp-menu-bundle` that is not yet supported by Sonata bundle.

Try requiring `knplabs/knp-menu-bundle` in `1.1.x`:

```
{
    ...
    "require": {
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "~1.1"
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: That did the trick. Using: 
`"knplabs/knp-menu": "~1.1", "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "~1.1"`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, but downgrade to Knpmenu version 1 is not possible for our project. Because of [some code update the June 16th](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/blob/ec09378a100dfe6285562e864c2286ef9104059e/Block/ProfileMenuBlockService.php#L87), it is now possible to use Sonata User Bundle and Knp Menu Version 2.

Please, have a look on my composer.json :

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3",
    "friendsofsymfony/message-bundle": "^1.2",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^2.3",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^2.3",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.1",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "~2.2,>=2.2.7,<2.3",
    "sonata-project/exporter": "^1.4",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "^2.2",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "~2.0",
    "knplabs/knp-menu": "~2.0"
},
```

As you can see, sonata-project/user-bundle is under dev-master version and I had to add sonata-project/datagrid-bundle in dev-master

Hope to help developpers who want want to preserve KnpMenu V2 !

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, This is my solution that you can preserve KnpMenu V2.

-You change setCurrentUri to setCurrent (because KNP changed code) in C:\path\vendor\sonata-project\user-bundle\Block\ProfileMenuBlockService.php

-You can have this problem, [Method "currentAncestor" for object "Knp\Menu\MenuItem" does not exist in Sonata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793518/method-currentancestor-for-object-knp-menu-menuitem-does-not-exist-in-sonata)

And this works for me.