# Method "currentAncestor" for object "Knp\Menu\MenuItem" does not exist in Sonata

Tags: symfony, authentication, sonata-admin, user-profile, sonata-user-bundle

I'm new to Symfony2 and I just installed it along with fosUserBUndle 1.3.3, Sonata Admin  BUndle, and Sonata User BUndle. Now I get an error that I cannot resolve.

**Here is my error:**

(url **localhost:8000/profile/** ) :

```
Method "currentAncestor" for object "Knp\Menu\MenuItem" does not exist in 

SonataBlockBundle:Block:block_side_menu_template.html.twig at line 29
```

I am able to login succesfully, but I get this error after login.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

open file block_side_menu_template.html.twig  at /var/www/html/MySymProject/vendor/sonata-project/block-bundle/Resources/views/Block/block_side_menu_template.html.twig

look at line 22 :

```
{%- if item.current %}
{%- set classes = classes|merge([options.currentClass]) %}
{%- elseif item.currentAncestor %}
{%- set classes = classes|merge([options.ancestorClass]) %}
{%- endif %}
```

Edit to :

```
{%- if matcher.isCurrent(item) %}
{%- set classes = classes|merge([options.currentClass]) %}
{%- elseif matcher.isAncestor(item, options.depth) %} 
{%- set classes = classes|merge([options.ancestorClass]) %}
{%- endif %}
```

you can visit this link below to find the answer :

https://gist.github.com/mrflory/2278437#file-knp_menu-html-twig-L22

Comment: or change knp-menu-bundle version to v2.0.0, officially sonataUserBUndle (dev-master) require 1.1.*, but sonataUserBUndle 1.1.* will not work with symfony 2.4