# Attempted to call an undefined method named "setCurrentUri" of class "Knp\Menu\MenuItem"

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-user-bundle, knpmenubundle

i'm trying to configure sonataUserBundle and fosUserBundle. when i try to access to my profile page , i got this error :

```
    Attempted to call an undefined method named "setCurrentUri" of class "Knp\Menu\MenuItem".
Did you mean to call "setCurrent"?
```

In my composer.json in have this version of  "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle":  "~2.0",

I downgraded to version "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "~1.1". but when i tried to update composer i got a error that says :

```
Problem 1
    - sonata-project/admin-bundle 2.4.x-dev requires knplabs/knp-menu-bundle >=2
.0,<3.0.0 -> no matching package found.
    - sonata-project/admin-bundle 2.4.x-dev requires knplabs/knp-menu >=2.0,<3.0
 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for sonata-project/admin-bundle ~2.4@dev -> satisfiab
le by sonata-project/admin-bundle[2.4.x-dev].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your min
imum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> f
or more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further commo
n problems.
```

Someone have any idea how to solve this error ?

[Call to method setCurrentUri fails in Symfony/SonataUserBundle setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188768/call-to-method-setcurrenturi-fails-in-symfony-sonatauserbundle-setup)

Thank you

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }

    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
        "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.6.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.12",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "leafo/lessphp": "*",
        "twitter/bootstrap": "*",
        "mremi/contact-bundle": "dev-master",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "2.3.*",
        "genemu/form-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "components/jquery":"dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3",
        "hwi/oauth-bundle": "0.4.*@dev",

        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "2.2.4",
        "sonata-project/core-bundle":  "~2.3@dev,>=2.3.1",
        "sonata-project/block-bundle": "~2.3@dev",
        "sonata-project/page-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony-cmf/routing-bundle": "~1.1",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle":  "~2.0",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "~2.4@dev",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle":  "~2.4@dev",
        "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "~2.1"

    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "symfony-assets-install":"symlink",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.7-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm still stack here with my error, please someone can help me ? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem but downgrade to Knpmenu version 1 is not possible for our project. Because of [some code update the June 16th](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/blob/ec09378a100dfe6285562e864c2286ef9104059e/Block/ProfileMenuBlockService.php#L87), we can now use Sonata User Bundle and Knp Menu Version 2.

Please, have a look on my composer.json :

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3",
    "friendsofsymfony/message-bundle": "^1.2",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^2.3",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^2.3",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.1",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "~2.2,>=2.2.7,<2.3",
    "sonata-project/exporter": "^1.4",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "^2.2",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "~2.0",
    "knplabs/knp-menu": "~2.0"
},
```

As you can see, sonata-project/user-bundle is under dev-master version and I had to add sonata-project/datagrid-bundle in dev-master

Hope to help you !

Answer (score 2):

hat versions of KnpMenu and SonataBlockBundle are you using? Please check your composer.json to be sure.

The setCurrentUri method has been deprecated as of KnpMenu v. 2.0, and the composer.json of SonataBlockBundle does not require KnpMenu anywhere but in dev install. So, this leads to a possibility that you could have required a fresher version of knplabs/knp-menu-bundle that is not yet supported by Sonata bundle.

Try requiring knplabs/knp-menu-bundle in 1.1.x:

```
{
...
"require": {
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "~1.1"
},
...
}
```

Comment: i'm using: "sonata-project/block-bundle": "~2.3@dev", and  "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "~2.0",.      i tried version  "~1.1" of knp menu bundle but it not working i got a  error when i tried to update composer.

Comment: i'm so surprised that only (Ralph Melhem) have been able to help me on this forum. Because there are a lot of people on this forum with good computer skills in programming. Thank you  Ralph Melhem. to fix my error you should use these different versions of the bundles below:   "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "~2.0", "sonata-project/user-bundle": "2.3.*@dev", "sonata-project/block-bundle": "~2.3@dev", "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "~2.4@dev",

Comment: @Dario glad i was able to help you, please mark my answer as the correct one; Cheers