# Overload a bundle with Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

So, the problem with my fresh installation of Symfony 2.7.9 is that SonataUserBundle didn't update their dependencies and I'm stuck with a buggy bundle (I already tried to upgrade to a greater version without success).

Here's the error :

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "setCurrentUri" of class "Knp\Menu\MenuItem".Did you mean to call "setCurrent"?
```

Which is thrown in the Sonata/Userbundle/Block/ProfileMenuBlockService.php at line 91

```
$menu->setCurrentUri($settings['current_uri']);
```

Therefore, I want to overload this file in my Application/Sonata/UserBundle but I don't understand why it won't work.

Here's what I did :

I copied the file responsible under Application/Sonata/UserBundle/Block/

```
<?php
namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Block;

use Knp\Menu\ItemInterface;
use Knp\Menu\Provider\MenuProviderInterface;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockContextInterface;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\Service\MenuBlockService;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Model\BlockInterface;
use Sonata\UserBundle\Menu\ProfileMenuBuilder;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

/**
 * Class ProfileMenuBlockService
 *
 * @package Sonata\UserBundle\Block
 *
 * @author Hugo Briand <briand@ekino.com>
 */
class ProfileMenuBlockService extends MenuBlockService
{
    /**
     * @var ProfileMenuBuilder
     */
    private $menuBuilder;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param string                $name
     * @param EngineInterface       $templating
     * @param MenuProviderInterface $menuProvider
     * @param ProfileMenuBuilder    $menuBuilder
     */
    public function __construct($name, EngineInterface $templating, MenuProviderInterface $menuProvider, ProfileMenuBuilder $menuBuilder)
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $templating, $menuProvider, array());

        $this->menuBuilder = $menuBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'User Profile Menu';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setDefaultSettings(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        parent::setDefaultSettings($resolver);

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'cache_policy' => 'private',
            'menu_template' => "SonataBlockBundle:Block:block_side_menu_template.html.twig",
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getMenu(BlockContextInterface $blockContext)
    {
        $settings = $blockContext->getSettings();

        $menu = parent::getMenu($blockContext);

        if (null === $menu || "" === $menu) {
            $menu = $this->menuBuilder->createProfileMenu(
                array(
                    'childrenAttributes' => array('class' => $settings['menu_class']),
                    'attributes'         => array('class' => $settings['children_class']),
                )
            );
            $menu->setCurrent($settings['current_uri']); // The corrected line
        }

        return $menu;
    }
}
```

As it didn't worked, I also overloaded the configuration file Sonata/UserBundle/Resources/config/block.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>
        <service id="sonata.user.block.menu" class="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Block\ProfileMenuBlockService">
            <tag name="sonata.block" />
            <argument>sonata.user.block.menu</argument>
            <argument type="service" id="templating" />
            <argument type="service" id="knp_menu.menu_provider" />
            <argument type="service" id="sonata.user.profile.menu_builder" />
        </service>

        <service id="sonata.user.block.account" class="Sonata\UserBundle\Block\AccountBlockService">
            <tag name="sonata.block" />
            <argument>sonata.user.block.account</argument>
            <argument type="service" id="templating" />
            <argument type="service" id="security.context" />
        </service>
    </services>

</container>
```

Do you see anything that I am missing ?

Not to mention that I already cleared the cache and even rebooted my computer.

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Please look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188768/call-to-method-setcurrenturi-fails-in-symfony-sonatauserbundle-setup and tell us if it worked ;)

Comment: I already tried this and it didn't work neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After pavlovich suggestion, I tried again [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188768/call-to-method-setcurrenturi-fails-in-symfony-sonatauserbundle-setup) which failed before and failed once again. Then, I noticed the comment of the correct answer and tried it too : it failed as I was already using sonata-project/user-bundle 2.2.5. I then used the following command :

```
composer require composer require knplabs/knp-menu ~1.1 knplabs/knp-menu-bundle ~1.1 sonata-project/user-bundle 2.2.4
```

Which worked but I got another error with a missing dependency for a sonata service. I therefore rolled back to sonata-project/user-bundle 2.2.5, which didn't update the knplabs/*-bundle versions.

To my own surprise, it actually resolved my problem.